# How to replace characters in a string in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, jira, jira-rest-api

I want to change a URL to make it into the API compatible form.

If I have the string: "https://MYSERVER.com/browse/BIT-1234?jql=projectXXXXXX"

I want to change it into: "https://MYSERVER.com/rest/api/latest/search?jql=projectXXXXXX"

I use an InputBox to get the URL and I want to change it to that form and put it back into the script as shown below. How do I this?

```
Dim response As String
With CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
myURL= Application.InputBox("Enter the URL")
//CHANGE THE URL SOMEHOW

.Open "GET", myURL(changed URL goes here), False, **USERNAME**, **PASSWORD**
.send
response = .responseText
End With
```

Comment: Is it just the `projectXXXXXX"` that you're actually interested in parsing out from the user input? Will there be always be `?jql=` before it?

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim response As String, arr

myURL= Application.InputBox("Enter the URL")
arr = Split(myUrl, "?")

If ubound(arr) = 1 Then
    With CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

        myUrl = "https://MYSERVER.com/rest/api/latest/search?" & arr(1)

        .Open "GET", myURL, False, **USERNAME**, **PASSWORD**
        .send
        response = .responseText

    End With
Else
    Msgbox "URL has no querystring!"
End If
```